# Problem with UV mapping/bake AO

Tags: game-engine, uv

I got an issue with a mesh I created.
I unwrapped it, baked it, and exported to a game in the proper format.
The thing is that is looks like the UV mapping got mix in some triangles (areas) of the mesh.

[image: Mesh looks fine in Blender - UV unwrapped and Bake]
[image: Mesh in game - ETS2]

Comment: Bake AO          http://abload.de/img/hood_midulqwk.png

Comment: UV Mapping   http://abload.de/img/hood_uv_midd0pu5.png

Comment: You have 2 UVMaps, i think you need to remove one of them that does not use the baked texture

Comment: I will try it Denis. Thanks. I'll come back and post results.

Comment: No, problem continues. I now have the mesh with only 1 Uv channel

Comment: Can you add the blend file?

Comment: I tried importing the file I export from blender, instead of continue working on the .blend file. And I found that the 1 UV channel was not exported properly.            http://abload.de/img/hood_blender2l3rch.png

Comment: I fixed it. I was using UV smart Project to Uv mapping, the game possibly can't handle it. Tried using UV Wrap instead, and worked fine. Thanks Denis for the help I think this is pretty much closed.

Comment: you could post your findings as an answer and mark it as correct if you want to.

Comment: @Manu the problem starts in your uvmap, they are quite bad, you can texturize in blender your model and give the appearance you want in your model, but the uvmap that you use for bake must have a stricter order and be cleaner, you will use project unwrap no It affects where the support what affects is that your uvs are very bad